# C# throwing an exception error as soon as one or more file contains invalid characters in a folder

Tags: c#, getfiles

I am trying to create an app in c# that will list all files with some info's plus will list all the files or folders contains invalid characters in a name or having too long path.
with this code

```
private void preCheckUploadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog selFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    selFolder.Description = "Select a folder";
    var selFolderResponse = selFolder.ShowDialog();
    if (selFolderResponse != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    logFile = selFolderName;
    try
    {
        createList(selFolder.SelectedPath);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLog(logFile , "error;" + ex.Message );
    }
}

private void createList(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        var filesInDir = Directory.GetFiles(sDir);
        foreach (string f in filesInDir)
        {
            WriteLog(logFile, "ok;" + f);
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException aexc)
    {
        WriteLog(logFile, "error;" + aexc.Message + sDir);              
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException pexc)
    {
        WriteLog(logFile", "error;" + pexc.Message + sDir);    
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sDir))
            try
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                createList(d);
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                WriteLog(logFile, "error;" + excpt.Message + ";the whole folder will be skipped;" + sDir);
            }
    }
}
```

at `Directory.GetFiles(sDir)` I am getting an `ArgumentException` error with illegal characters in a path and it's skipping the whole folder. I am not able to list the files which contains illegal characters.
I have also tried

```
try
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir))
    {
        WriteLog(logFile, "ok;" + f);
    }
    catch( exception)
    {
    }
```

Here I am getting list only till the valid files but once its encountering with an error it's skipping rest of the folder and I am also not able to get a filename contains invalid characters.

Comment: What is the sDir value you call Directory.GetFiles(sDir) with? I would guess it has an invalid character in it.

Comment: You are not closing your `try` blocks... I'm unsure whether this code can actually compile. Also, maybe if you `try/catch` *inside* the loop, it won't skip the rest of the folder whenever there's an invalid character in a file

Comment: After re-reading your question, it seems like as PepitoSh said, it's **not** the **files** which contains illegal characters, but the `sDir` you are passing to `Directory.GetFiles(sDir)`

Comment: Initially sDir is FolderBrowserDialog selFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog(); sDir = selFolder.SelectedPath and then with Directory.getdirectory i am reading subdirectoris

Comment: Please edit your post to include that. Also maybe set a breakpoint and tell us what's `sDir` value at the moment of the call to `Directory.GetFiles`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to check for invalid chars in the path

```
 var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
        bool bInvalid = invalidChars .Any(s1 => sDir.IndexOf(s1 )!=-1);
```